# Why does my cost for a clustered index scan increase when narrowing down the where clause on a different table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I have a simplified query like this

```
SELECT a.OrderInfoID, a.SalesReceiptID, SUM(b.Qty) AS Qty
FROM dbo.OrderInfo a
INNER JOIN dbo.OrderInfoSequential b ON a.OrderInfoSequentialID=b.OrderInfoID
WHERE a.OrderID=12345
GROUP BY a.OrderInfoID, a.SalesReceiptID
```

The query plan shows a clustered index scan on `dbo.OrderInfoSequential` for about 1s, which makes sense because there is no index yet.

However when I change the where clause to

```
WHERE a.OrderID=12345 AND a.SalesReceiptID=123
```

The time for the clustered index scan increases to over 3s.

I don't understand this because it should search for the exact same thing or even less (because specifying the `SalesReceiptID` should result in less `OrderInfo` records found that need to be joined in the first place.

What am I not understanding about this correctly?

*Edit: Removed (NOLOCK) statements as they are not relevant to the question*

Comment: Are you actually timing the queries or basing your question on the estimated query plan?

Comment: Do you *really* need those `NOLOCK` hints? You do understand what they do, correct? [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) Also, `a` is an odd alias for `OrderInfo`, when there's no "a" in "OrderInfo", and there also no "b" in "OrderInfoSequential". [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: @GordonLinoff I ran the queries on a database with about 10 million entries. And then looked at the execution plan to get these time estimates.

Comment: @Larnu I narrowed down the example a bit, hence the table aliases a and b. Regarding the (NOLOCK): this is a legacy codebase, so I am following the standard that was already there. No global transaction isolation levle is set, unfortunately.

Comment: Just because the code (likely foolishly) implemented `NOLOCK` doesn't mean you should continue to without understanding the (severe) consequences it can have, @kapuetze .

Comment: @Larnu I'll keep that in mind

Comment: You can [paste the plans](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for comparison. My unfounded speculation would be that the condition causes the optimizer to estimate fewer rows matching the condition (partially based on the statistics, partially on guesswork) and this in turn causes it to choose a different strategy for the join, or memory allocations going wayward. Getting fewer rows isn't always a good thing, as it can cause the selection of strategies that are only correct for even *smaller* numbers of rows -- that is, you'd be better off with the "slow" strategy.